# Instruction on installing MyPaint for macOS Catalina 10.15.4

Tags: macos, installation, macos-catalina

MyPaint (drawing app) looks really promising and I've been trying to install it for a while now but with no success.

The videos I found on YouTube are outdated so the installation steps don't work and I am not aware of what to do with the most recent GitHub repository of myPaint.

I've tried to contact some of the developers on Twitter but they haven't replied.

Does anyone know the steps or is aware of a video that would guide me how to install and open myPaint on my macOS Catalina 10.15.4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to their site, the Mac version is available via MacPorts.  That being said, there are a number of requirements under Catalina (XCode, command-line developers tools, X11), so it looks as though it won't run native Mac, but will run as an Xwindows app.  Also, the version I see available with MacPorts is 1.2.1, rather than the new 2.0.0 release available on github.  MacPorts has requirements of its own (tcl, curl, sqlite, mtree, rsync...).  Basically, you'll be compiling the source yourself rather than relying on a drop-in application.

It may be a rather ambitious undertaking.  I'm not sure how easy it would be to cover in a video, and documenting the steps would be a bit of a project itself.  May be worth it, but it may be easier to [try something else that's written for Mac](https://www.techjunkie.com/best-free-drawing-apps-mac/)